# How can I open multiple attachments of the same name in an email, then move the sender of the attachment to a spreadsheet?

Tags: perl, email, batch-file, autohotkey

I have an internship and was recently assigned the tedious task of cleaning the email lists.  My employer has sent me a series of email with email bounces as attachments, many at a time, all with the same name.  I have considered ways of doing this most efficiently, I'm looking to avoid just clicking through like a slave.  My thoughts were to create a macro using autohotkey's language, but I feel like maybe a batch file or some sort of Perl might do the same thing.  Could anybody give me an idea as to how to do this, specifically with a batch file?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could be done in Perl, for sure, and quickly.  It's just a matter of looking at your input, finding what you want, and dumping it out to a CSV file to import into Excel for further processing.  Can you post a sample of the input, and scrub any identifiable information out of it?

Answer (score 1):

[Mail::DeliveryStatus::BounceParser](http://p3rl.org/Mail%3a%3aDeliveryStatus%3a%3aBounceParser) parses bouncing email addresses out of delivery report messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know any perl, then I recommend that you first convert the mailbox into some format that stores each email in separate text files, like [MH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH_Message_Handling_System) or similar.

At that point, you can trivially use the command `grep _pattern_ | sed -e 's/:.*//' | sort | uniq > _list_` to obtain lists of all files matching `_pattern_`.  You may inspect/edit this file `_list_` to verify that the desired results were obtained.

You may then create another director `junk` or whatever and move all the files listed in `_list_` into `junk` with a command like `perl -e 'chomp; rename($_,"junk");' < _list_`.

If you'll need this regularly, then you could automate this further, likely using perl alone, but a one off task will probably involve more messing about with getting the right message list.

Alternatively, you could load all the emails into a single folder in an sane mail reader, like Mac OS X's Mail.app, and do simply search, select all, move/delete commands.

Comment: wow, maybe perl isn't for me, lol.  I appreciate the response, but is there any way you could give me a good MH program (I don't have an Emac, just running windows vista here)  Also, where would I enter your code?  Or, could you direct me to a sane mail reader for windows? Thanks for you response!

Comment: You might also check out the command procmail and its config file procmailrc which lets you define rules, that'll process it in mbox format.